# WebRequest Credentials in BizTalk WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, biztalk

I have a custom WCF Service that uses WebRequest to update a file on my SharePoint site.  But I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error when attempting to use the service after it has been deployed to BizTalk.

I've tried setting the credentials for the WebRequest object and it will work if I hard code an actual account.  But that 's not something I can leave lying around.

Has anyone had to develop a custom BizTalk service that uses WebRequest to modify SharePoint?  How did you go about handling the credentials?

Location of Error

```
 public static void uploadSharePointFile(Uri fileUri, byte[] myByteArray, ref List<string> result)
 {
        Stream dataStream = null;
        WebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            result.Add("Requesting PUT of SharePoint File\n  " + fileUri.ToString());
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fileUri);
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            request.ContentLength = myByteArray.Length;
            result.Add("File Size: " + request.ContentLength + " Bytes");
            dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            result.Add("Data stored to SharePoint File");

            response = request.GetResponse();
            result.Add("Response Status Description: " + ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            result.Add("(401) Unauthorized");
            result.Add(e.InnerException.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dataStream != null) dataStream.Close();
            if (response != null) response.Close();
        }
}
```

Web.Config

```
enter code here
<configuration>

  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="65536000" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000" maxBufferPoolSize="65536000">
          <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="65536000" maxArrayLength="65536000" maxDepth="65536000"/></binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="65536000" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000" maxBufferPoolSize="65536000">
          <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="65536000" maxArrayLength="65536000" maxDepth="65536000"/></binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

`

Comment: I noticed you're adding `result.Add("(401) Unauthorized");` in your catch block. I assume you're getting actual 401 responses?

Comment: @Tom Redfern that is correct.  It just makes it easier for me to distinguish the problem during testing at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set permissions on SharePoint for the list/library I was trying to modify.  I was too fixated on one end of the service, that I forgot to consider the other.

And I added `<Authentication mode = "Windows"/>` to the web.config.  I am not certain if that actually did anything, but it's not breaking the service.